# Integration test with SpringFramework Java

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying to make a integration test using Spring Framework. Till now i have some code but i do not understand how to fix the exception.

**This is the controller that i want to integration test.**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        LoginModel form = new LoginModel();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        // destination page in profiles
        if (request.getParameter("dest") != null && !request.getParameter("dest").trim().equals("")) {
            try {
                form.setDestPage(msa.getMessage("configure.path." + request.getParameter("dest").trim()));
            } catch (NoSuchMessageException ig) {
                logger.error(ig.getMessage());
                form.setDestPage(msa.getMessage("configure.path.home"));
            }
        } else {
            form.setDestPage(msa.getMessage("configure.path.home"));
        }

        // return path
        if (request.getParameter("retpath") != null && !request.getParameter("retpath").trim().equals("")) {
            String retpath = request.getParameter("retpath").trim();
             if (!(retpath.matches("^http[s]?://mail[0-9]{2}\\.asd\\.bg.*")
                     || retpath.matches("^http[s]?://nm[0-9]?[0-9]?\\.asd\\.bg.*")
                     || retpath.matches("^http[s]?://asd.*\\.ni\\.bg.*")|| retpath.matches("^http[s]?://dox\\.asd\\.bg.*")
                     || retpath.matches("^http[s]?://asdwfs\\.ni\\.bg.*"))) {
                 retpath = "";

             }
            form.setRetPath(retpath);
        }

        // email address
        if (request.getParameter("email") != null && !request.getParameter("email").trim().equals("")) {
            form.setEmail(request.getParameter("email").trim());
        }

        model.addAttribute("form", form);
        return formView;
    }
}
```

For the test i am using db unit and i try to make a in-memory database.
**LoginControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value="/login.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("classpath:applicationContext.xml").build();
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("/login.xml")
    public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("id", nullValue())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
    }
}
```

**login.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataset>
        <Person id="1" email="test@something.com" username="qwerty"
            hostname="something.com" pass="password1234" />

        <Person id="2" email="test1@something.com" username="qwerty"
            hostname="something.com" pass="password1234" />
    </dataset>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load dataset from "/login.xml" using class com.github.springtestdbunit.dataset.FlatXmlDataSetLoader
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.loadDataset(DbUnitRunner.java:137)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:153)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:70)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBefores(SpringMethodRoadie.java:315)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load dataset from "/login.xml" using class com.github.springtestdbunit.dataset.FlatXmlDataSetLoader
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.loadDataset(DbUnitRunner.java:137)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:122)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:80)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:340)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:351)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:262)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**UPDATE**
After i fix login.xml location this is the new exception.

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: Person
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:288)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:159)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:70)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBefores(SpringMethodRoadie.java:315)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: table count expected:<[1]> but was:<[0]>
    at org.dbunit.assertion.JUnitFailureFactory.createFailure(JUnitFailureFactory.java:39)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DefaultFailureHandler.createFailure(DefaultFailureHandler.java:105)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:237)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:205)
    at org.dbunit.Assertion.assertEquals(Assertion.java:104)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.assertion.DefaultDatabaseAssertion.assertEquals(DefaultDatabaseAssertion.java:33)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:128)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:80)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:340)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:351)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:262)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: have you tried to add prefix classpath:login.xml

Comment: @hasnae i tried but it did not work.

Comment: Your new update is a totally different question.  Raise another question for that please.

Comment: And, your problem has nothing to do with the Controller logic nor the test logic.  Please put only relevant information there. (It should be something that you can easily identify by putting a empty test, with a dummy controller)

Answer (score 0):

according to the source code, you're getting this exception because the dataset is `null`. I guess that the integration test cannot find the `/login.xml` file and is complaining about that.

Try specifying the absolute path of the `login.xml`, to see if the problem is in finding the dataset.

```
@DatabaseSetup(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value="ABSOLUTE_PATH_HERE/login.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the document: https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/

As you have declared

```
@DatabaseSetup(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value="/login.xml")
```

You should put the xml in the root of, for example in standard maven layout, `test/resources`.  (or other appropriate place, so that it can be located as resource with path `/login.xml`)

---

Your next update is something irrelevant.

DB Unit simply cannot find the `Person` table to do insert.  It is something we can never know the reason of.  Check your DB and make sure the DB your tests connecting to is having the table required

Comment: I saw that the login.xml was not where it must be. Now i have a new exception. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Just a reminder: if it is unrelated to the original question, please raise a new question.

Comment: i will add a new question.